# Understanding Semaphore in C

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

I've successfully implemented Mutex locks and Conditional Variable locks in C and trying to achieve the same using semaphore. Below is my code, but when executing, the output is always 24 instead of 12. Help me understanding how to use semaphore please.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_THREADS  2
#define TCOUNT 12
#define COUNT_LIMIT 12

int count = 0;
sem_t sem;

void *dum(void *t_id){
    long id = long(t_id);
    for (int i = 0; i < TCOUNT; i++) {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        count++;
        sem_post(&sem);
        printf("In Dum(). Count :: %d. Thread :: %ld \n", count, id);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    long t1=1, t2=2;
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, dum, (void *)t1);
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, dum, (void *) t2);
    for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf ("Main(): Waited on %d  threads. Done.\n", NUM_THREADS);
    printf ("Count should be 12. Actual Count: %d. \n", count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
In Dum(). Count :: 1. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 2. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 3. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 4. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 5. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 6. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 7. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 8. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 9. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 10. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 11. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 13. Thread :: 1 
In Dum(). Count :: 13. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 14. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 15. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 16. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 17. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 18. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 19. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 20. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 21. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 22. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 23. Thread :: 2 
In Dum(). Count :: 24. Thread :: 2 
Main(): Waited on 2  threads. Done.
Count should be 12. Actual Count: 24.
```

Comment: By the way, you've got an off-by-one bug in your program... You need to use the indices 0 and 1 rather than 1 and 2. You're lucky it's not crashing, though it might be causing you unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Unrelated: `long id = long(t_id);` ? Maybe my C compiler is a little *too* ancient. Did I miss another memo, because clang 3.8 compiling C11 pukes on that.

Comment: Related: you have two threads that are hard-coded to loop for 12 iterations **each**. One way or another, so long as your semaphore does its job, you'll end up with a total of 24 increments between the two. If that isn't what you intended, then the code is wrong. Hint: `COUNT_LIMIT` is suspiciously defined, but completely unused in the posted code.

Comment: Program is running almost as it should ( output wise ), you are counting `i` up to `12` twice, so `count` will be `i*2` or `24`

Comment: @Serdalis: How do I make it run upto only 12 by both threads using semaphore?

Answer (score 1):

As kcraigie said you're indexing the threads array wrong. Also it would be better to pass t1 and t2 by pointer:

```
void *dum(void *t_id)
{
    long id = *(long*)t_id;
```

and

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, dum, (void *) &t1);
pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, dum, (void *) &t2);
for (i=0; i<2; i++) 
{
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Also in your thread you lock the semaphore, increment count and release the semaphore, and then you print it. There's no guarantee that the value you print out will be the value of count after you'd incremented it. The other thread may already have done so too. Put the printf inside the semaphore lock:

```
sem_wait(&sem);
count++;
printf("In Dum(). Count :: %d. Thread :: %ld \n", count, id);
sem_post(&sem);
```

But otherwise counting to 24 seems to be the correct behaviour. You have two loops spread across 2 threads each iterating 12 times adding one to count. The fact that one of them gets to complete its loop first followed by the other is probably because the thread that's started first gets all its work done inside a single timeslice before the main thread has had a chance to start thread 2.

Comment: What I'm asking is, both threads should execute the function dum() and the final count value has to be only 12. Why? if it is only one thread, output is 12. But with both threads in place with semaphore lock, it should also be 12 right? say t1 will count till 6 and t2 has to take it up from 6 and count to 12.

Comment: Both threads loop TCOUNT times. The sem_wait takes the semaphore, the sem_post relinquishes the semaphore. Ownership of the semaphore after sem_wait does not magically make the other thread skip an iteration of its for loop. It simply means that any other thread calling sem_wait stops until sem_post has been called.